# Unexpected Behavior of "if" statement when using "=" to test for equality

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom-events

I have the following JavaScript code, used to replace the code contained in a `<div>` of the page with a portion from another:

```
    function ReplaceContentInContainer(etiqueta) {
        var container = document.getElementById('contenedor');
        if (etiqueta="esTransportista") {
            container.innerHTML = document.getElementById('transportista').innerHTML;
        } else if (etiqueta="esCargador") {
            container.innerHTML = document.getElementById('cargador').innerHTML;
        }

    }
```

Then I call it from the page with the following code:

```
<input type='radio' name='esTransportista' id='esTransportista' value='1' onclick="javascript:ReplaceContentInContainer(esTransportista);">Es transportista <br />
<input type='radio' name='esTransportista' id='esCargador' value='0' onclick="javascript:ReplaceContentInContainer(esCargador);" checked>Es cargador <br />
```

And, finally, I have three `<div>'s` in my page, one to display the information `< div id='contenedor'>< /div>` and the other two containing the code to be displayed in this `id='contenedor'` I mentioned (being them `<div id='transportista'>bla bla bla< /div>` and `< div id='cargador'>bla2 bla2 bla2< /div>`).

The problem I face is that the JavaScript code seems to work just once. It changes the content of 'contenedor' the first time I check one of the radio buttons, but if I check the other one the JavaScript doesn't work anymore.

Is there any way I could make the JavaScript code work every time I click on any of the radio buttons?

I've been googling and most of the results I surfed refer to jQuery and bounding to elements that are vanished, but this is not my case, as far as I know...

Answer (score 2):

Just doing a quick scan of you code and saw that your `if (etiqueta="esTransportista")` statement is incorrect.
When comparing two objects you need the ==

Try

```
  function ReplaceContentInContainer(etiqueta) {
        var container = document.getElementById('contenedor');
        if (etiqueta=="esTransportista") {
            container.innerHTML = document.getElementById('transportista').innerHTML;
        } else if (etiqueta=="esCargador") {
            container.innerHTML = document.getElementById('cargador').innerHTML;
        }

    }
```

Comment: `===` is preferable to `==`.

Comment: @JLRishe – That really depends on the context.  For those wondering, a `===` call is a type-dependent _exact_ match, while `==` is a non-type-dependent _soft_ match.  `'true' == true` returns `true`, `'true' === true` returns false.

Comment: @JoshBurgess No, it doesn't really depend on the context. `==`'s behavior is bizarre and hard to predict, and the prevailing wisdom is to never use it (http://stackoverflow.com/a/359509/1945651). And FYI, `'true' == true` evaluates to `false`. See what I mean about it being hard to predict?

Comment: A bit of a side note, but this answer is incomplete.

Answer (score 2):

Your javascript has a small error:

```
function ReplaceContentInContainer(etiqueta) {
        var container = document.getElementById('contenedor');
        if (etiqueta == "esTransportista") {
            container.innerHTML = document.getElementById('transportista').innerHTML;
        } else if (etiqueta == "esCargador") {
            container.innerHTML = document.getElementById('cargador').innerHTML;
        }
    }
```

Notice in the if statement you had `etiqueta = "esTransportista"`. That would make it save "esTransportista" to etiqueta and it would go into that part of the if statement.

By changing the `=` to `==` you compare to see if it is true.

**EDIT**

You should also change in your `onclick="..."` sections to put the names in single quotes:

```
onclick="javascript:ReplaceContentInContainer('esTransportista');"
onclick="javascript:ReplaceContentInContainer('esCargador');"
```

That ensures that the javascript does not look for variables with those names and knows that you are passing strings.

Comment: This answer is incomplete.

Answer (score 2):

There are two things preventing your code from working correctly:

- You are passing undefined variables to your function instead of strings
- You are using `=` where you should be using `===`

The JavaScript expression you are using in your click handler is this:

```
ReplaceContentInContainer(esTransportista);
```

here, `esTransportista` is a *variable reference*, but since you don't have a variable with that name, the value `undefined` is passed to your function.

Inside your function, `etiqueta` has the value `undefined`, but when this `if` statement executes

```
if (etiqueta = "esTransportista") {
    container.innerHTML = document.getElementById('transportista').innerHTML;
}
```

the *asssignment operator* `=` assigns the value `"esTransportista"` to `etiqueta`, and then this value is passed onto the `if` statement. `"esTransportista"` is "truthy", so the body of that `if` block will always run.

---

To get your code to work as expected,

1. Pass string values to your function, not undefined variables:

```js
ReplaceContentInContainer("esTransportista")  // note the quotes here    
ReplaceContentInContainer("esCargador")  // note the quotes here
```

2. Use the `===` operator to compare a variable against a value:

```js
if (etiqueta === "esTransportista") {
    container.innerHTML = document.getElementById('transportista').innerHTML;
} else if (etiqueta === "esCargador") {
    container.innerHTML = document.getElementById('cargador').innerHTML;
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rhw1kf0r/)

---

As one additional (albeit optional) improvement. I suggest setting up your click handlers in your code, not putting them in your HTML. One way to do so (without getting too fancy) would look like this:

```
window.onload = function () {
    document.getElementById("esTransportista").onclick = function () {
        ReplaceContentInContainer("esTransportista");
    };

    document.getElementById("esCargador").onclick = function () {
        ReplaceContentInContainer("esCargador"); 
    };
};
```

If you put that in your code, you can remove the `onclick` attributes on your radio buttons and leave them as:

```
<input type='radio' name='esTransportista' id='esTransportista' value='1'>Es transportista
<br />
<input type='radio' name='esTransportista' id='esCargador' value='0' checked>Es cargador
<br />
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hhbuyo0L/)